# TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' in pandas

Tags: pandas

I am comparing two columns in a pandas DF, A and B like this:

```
df['A'].gt(df['B'])
```

but get this error:

TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

when I lookup the dtypes:
df.dtypes

I see this output:

```
id: object
A: object
B: int64
```

when I look at 5 top records with
do df.head()

I see this:

```
id    A   B
a1    2   2.353566677998
a2    4   4.454444231211
a3    3   6.777888665343
.....
```

how to solve this error:

```
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

when doing this comparison:

df['A'].gt(df['B'])

Looks like many people are asking this but I couldn't find one that matches my issue!

Comment: Try `df['A'] = pd.to_numeric(df['A'], errors='coerce')` before comparison?

Comment: This one worked thank you Quang Hoang

Answer (score 2):

Although the values are clearly integers when you look at the DataFrame, pandas uses `object` for `str` values - which from the error, is what you have. You can cast all of the values of the `A` column to integers though, and you should be good to go!

`df["A"] = df["A"].astype(int)`

Comment: this one returned an error "invalid literal for int() with base 10..." but thanks anyway Alex Watt

Comment: This is the correct answer. Please show the full message error you got @alexr. This is probably a `ValueError`, then it should show the first value that break the conversion. Also, try to use `float` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working with Google Colab? If thats the case, then do both: restart runtime and restart everything. It usually works.